# $http GET parameters are not read by servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I'm sending userId from Angular $http call. The servlet is hitting, but its not able to receive the request parameter. I'm fetching the request parameter by request.getParameter("userId");

Here is the code

```
    $scope.getDetailsFromServer = function() {      
        $http({
           method: 'GET',           
           url: 'dashboardDetailsOfUser',
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           data:"userId="+ $scope.userId
           }).success(function (data){
            $scope.status=data;
           }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("error");
       });      
    }
```

### My servlet code

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = "";
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection();
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String user_id = request.getParameter("userId");
        System.out.println("User ID :"+user_id);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(result);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");         
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything missing in the code of Angular or Servlet?

Comment: Yes, you're not consistent in your naming. You said you're using user_id, but you're looking for userId. Also, please keep your code example a bit more focussed on this problem you're having.

Comment: @ErikPragt, okay I've edited the question. It was a typo. Please check it

Comment: Your HTTP get is probably wrong. It needs to look like this: $http({
    url: 'dashboardDetailsOfUser', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {userId: "123"}
 });

Comment: @ErikPragt that's correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client sends a GET request therefore the request body is [not](https://java.net/projects/servlet-spec/lists/users/archive/2013-02/message/54) used by the servlet to populate the request parameters.

Either send a POST and use `doPost` in the servlet, or a GET and include the userId parameter in the url.

Comment: Is that the only choice? I'm not sure about it. Plz correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Syed see servlet 3.1. spec, chapter "3.1.1 When Parameters Are Available". As a third option you could also parse the the request body on your own